# Error en una función plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Estoy haciendo una función plpgsql, que debo asociar a un trigger. Funciona cuando debe dar error, sin embargo, me dice que llega al final sin encontrar un `return` y no se que debería retornar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
set search_path to practica4;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION howManyEmployees() RETURNS trigger AS $$

DECLARE
    how_many NUMERIC(2);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO how_many FROM empleats
        WHERE departament = new.departament;
        IF how_many >= 3 THEN
            raise exception 'There are already 3 employes in the departament';
        END IF;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: no falta un return en algun lado?

Comment: Si, ese es el problema, no se que debe retornar la función

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltaba un return new; justo después de END IF; :

```
set search_path to practica4;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION howManyEmployees() RETURNS trigger AS $$

DECLARE
    how_many NUMERIC(2);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO how_many FROM empleats
        WHERE departament = new.departament;
        IF how_many >= 3 THEN
            raise exception 'There are already 3 employes in the departament';
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: detalla mejor el formato de esta respuesta si es que esto soluciona el problema